# What is the difference between the LT1054 from TI & the LT1054 from Linear Technologies, other than price

Tags: converter

The following has me puzzled:

The specifications on the datasheets of the LT1054 from Texas Instruments appear the same to me as those of the LT1054 from Linear Technologies.

In Europe the TI LT1054's cost half as much or less than the ones from Linear Technologies.

Have I missed something important on the datasheets that justify a higher/lower price between the two?

Comment: "In Europe". You checked price in 56 nations?

Comment: Which supplier(s) are you looking at?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about pricing policies between TI and LTI.

Comment: @pipe You made your point

Comment: @ThreephaseEel Seven major distributors

Comment: @Andy aka "You get what you pay for" is the driving factor of my question. I'm asking about eventual specification differences. Pricing policies did not come to my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Parts with the same part number *should* have exactly the same specs, even from different vendors. This allows for **second sourcing**, which makes it more likely that the part will be included in a design since there is no longer a dependence on the original vendor continuing to manufacture the part.

This doesn't mean that all vendors need to price them the same way though. If one of them has an advantage in manufacture then they are free to take advantage of that (unless there are licensing terms that say otherwise).

Comment: why is this downvoted?